# Rails Error: Bundle Install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bundle

After adding some gems, I run bundle install and get this error:

Gemfile syntax error:
source: rubygems

Here's my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'

end

gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. If you could please indent code inside your posts with four-space indenting, that'd make it easier to see. Thanks! What version of Bundler are you using?

Comment: not sure, how would i check that?

Comment: `bundle -v` would give you the version.

Comment: Also, what version of Ruby?  ruby -v gives that.

Comment: not sure how relevant this is, but also got this when installing ruby: Ruby 'ruby-1.9.3-p194' was built using clang - but it's not (fully) supported, expect errors.

Answer (score 0):

Its must be a version problem of ruby. your using rails 3.2.8 if your using ruby 1.8.7 or less then please install ruby 1.9.3. it will avoid your syntax error

Comment: i'm using ruby 1.9.3p194 (2012-04-20 revision 35410) [x86_64-darwin11.4.1]

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest you to write all gems independently instead of grouping them into your Gemfile. Because whatever gems your are grouped inside :development and :asset, no need to group them.

You should try in this way:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'
gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'
gem 'sass-rails',   '3.2.5'
gem 'coffee-rails', '3.2.2'
gem 'uglifier', '1.2.3'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

now run `bundle install` hope it will work for you.

Comment: This question is 2.5 years old. And `assets` group used to make sense in Rails 3, but no more in Rails 4. The question is about Rails 3.

Comment: I agree with you D-side.  I just joined Stackoverflow so hope you understand my answer.

Comment: Well, welcome then! I'm not the author of this question, so I don't need this answer. I just don't see how this answers the given question. Not that it actually matters, since your best bet for new projects is Rails 4.2 right now.